# Make external div grows/shrinks when internal div grows/shrinks but keeping a margin between them

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The issue that I'm trying to solve:

I have a external div which contains a div.

```
<div class="external">
    <div class="internal">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

The margin between the internal and external div should always be the same.

When the internal div grows/shrinks, the external div will modify its height & width to keep the specified margin with the internal div. Somehow the internal div is controlling the width & height of both divs. When the internal div grows the external div grows too to keep the margin. When the internal div shrinks the external does too to keep the margin.

Anyone? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a CSS thing by default:

```
#internal {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
#external {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Or you could animate the whole thing like this:

```
$("#internal").animate({width: "300px", height: "500px"}, {duration: 1000, step: function (now,PlainObject) {

    // PlainObject.prop is either 'width' or 'height'
    $("#external")[PlainObject.prop](PlainObject.now + 10);

}});
```

I assumed that the shrinking and growing happens when the inner div is animated? Or do you mean when the content of the inner div is larger / smaller (more/less text in the inner div)?

The `inline-block` property is just meant for a CSS-only solution. If you go for a dynamic javascript solution, you should set it to `display: block;`

Comment: Robin van Baalen, thanks for the answer. For your question, it is when the inner div is animated. Using display: inline-block will position the div as an inline element. So I wont be able to center it. This is supposed to be a div that will display a login/signup/forgetpassword dialogs. Those dialogs have different sizes. I have the fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/kitimenpolku/y76YW/ I'm new to fiddle so I did the basic to display the implementation. As you see, it is not center for every dialog.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't use one of the many excellent dialog library for this?

Comment: @kitimenpolku I updated my answer a bit to clarify thinks for you. Use `display:block;` if you are using javascript to manipulate the width and height properties.
P.S. if it is an answer, please mark it as one. This helps future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: could you tell me about those libraries?  Most popular ones?

Comment: @kitimenpolku [Use Google](https://www.google.com/?q=jquery+dialog) or take a look at Twitter Bootstrap for example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's your problem? Could you maybe provide some more detailed code/css? If you're trying following code you will see that the external div will grow/shrink, when you make any size changes on the inner div and the `margin: 10px` is kept in between.

```
// jQuery snippet tested in my browser's console:
$(document.body).append($('<div id="external">').append($('<div id="internal">').css({margin: '10px', backgroundColor: '#f00', height: '100px', width: '100px', display: 'inline-block'})).css({backgroundColor: '#000'}));

//resize:
$('#internal').height(200);
$('#internal').width(200);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use some padding on your external div without setting a fixed width or height. Let

Something like this: `.external { padding: 20px; }` You can also set max-width to the outer div if you need it.